# Association rules between many continuous variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, association-measure, association-rules

I have a large dataset and I'm trying to mining association rules between the variables.

My problem is that I have 160 variables among which I have to look for the association rules and also I have more than 1800 item-sets.

Furthermore my variables are continuous variables.
To mining association rules, I usually used the apriori algorithm, but as is well known, this algorithm requires the use of categorical variables.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what kind of algorithm I can use in this case?

A restricted example of my dataset is the following:

```
ID_Order   Model     ordered quantity
A.1        typeX     20
A.1        typeZ     10
A.1        typeY     5
B.2        typeX     16
B.2        typeW     12
C.3        typeZ     1
D.4        typeX     8
D.4        typeG     4
...
```

My goal would be to establish association rules and correlation between different products, maybe with a neural network algorithm in R
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance